# "Between" does not work, where is the mistake in my code?

Tags: c#, mysql, date

I would like to ask for help because for some reason, the SQL clause with BETWEEN does not work for me - I get 0 results.

When inserting the record, I store the date like this:

```
..
commandObject.Parameters.Add("date", c.Found.Date);
```

THe problem I have that this never works:

```
 commandObject.Parameters.Add("from", dateTimePicker_FROM.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());
                    commandObject.Parameters.Add("to", dateTimePicker_TO.Value.Date.ToShortDateString());
                    commandObject.CommandText = "Select * from Persons WHERE Date BETWEEN @from AND @to";
```

Other selects etc. work just fine.

Comment: Can you show us the output from `c.Date.ToShortDateString()` ?

Comment: can you please explain `doesn't work` more precisely? and provide some sample data? my first blind guess, though comes from `ToShortDateString` - why work with strings instead of datetimes in your database? they have different comparison behavior, and you _usually_ want datetime.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen WHen debugging, this gets stored in the parameter: {1/19/2021 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: use this CONVERT(datetime, @from)

Comment: In MySQL, dates must be 'y-m-d' and date times must be 'y-m-d h:i:s'

Answer (score 0):

When using the BETWEEN condition in MySQL with dates, be sure to use the CAST function to explicitly convert the values to dates.

The following date example uses the BETWEEN condition to retrieve values within a date range:

SELECT *
FROM example_tbl
WHERE order_date BETWEEN CAST('2021-01-19' AS DATE) AND CAST('2021-01-20' AS DATE);

more info at: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php

Comment: Thanks, the syntax worked but I still get 0 results :(

Comment: You don't need this cast; MySQL understands strings in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format as dates

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass your dates as dates, not strings:

```
 commandObject.Parameters.Add("from", dateTimePicker_FROM.Value.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why you seem to store a date (and make a date parameter) but when you do your search you use strings instead of dates

You said:

```
commandObject.Parameters.Add("date", c.Found.Date);
```

This seems wonky; I don't recall an overload of Add that takes a string and a value (assuming you use [the MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection.htm)) - did you mean AddWithValue?

I assume that:

- you meant to say AddWithValue
- your query looks like `INSERT INTO T VALUES(..., @date, ...)
- your parameter "date" is used against a column that stores a date, datetime or time stamp
- c.Found is a c# datetime, and you use the Date property to set the time to midnight

Supposing c.Found is `2020-01-02 12:34:56`, it means your table should end up with 2020-01-02 00:00:00

Now set your pickers  to 2020-01-01 and 2020-01-03

Run your search like:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE date BETWEEN @f AND @t
```

Set your parameters like:

```
commandObject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", fromPicker.Value.Date);
commandObject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", toPicker.Value.Date);
```

I.e. make them dates, not strings

And it will work

BETWEEN is inclusive at both ends of the range so the from picker or the to picker can be 2020-01-02 and it will still pick up. Consider dates to be like integers, with times to be like decimals. 2020-01-02 00:00:00 is like 2.0, 2020-01-02 18:00:00 is like 2.75, 2020-01-03 00:00:00 is like 3.0. This means that BETWEEN 2020-01-02 AND 2020-01-03 will pick up anything with midnight on those dates, and everything between, just like BETWEEN 2 AND 3 would give you rows with 2, 2.5, 3... but it won't give you 3.5, and similarly it won't give you 2020-01-03 12:00:00 if the between ends at 2020-01-03

Comment: Thanks, I use the embedded sqldatabase and the only method for adding a parameter pair is Add. There is no method AddWithValue.

Comment: You can just adjust the advice to use Add, then.. Or post some more info about exactly what you use. The only clue you give is the tag "mysql", hence why I targeted mySQL advice